# Densely-defined operator with closed range: conditions for operator closed

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Suppose we have Banach spaces (or Hilbert spaces) $X$ and $Y$,
and a densely-defined linear operator $A : \operatorname{dom}(A) \subset X \rightarrow Y$ that is densely-defined and with closed range. In other words, $\operatorname{dom}(A)$ is dense, and $\operatorname{rng} A$ is closed.

Under which conditions is $A$ a closed operator?

Comment: What sort of conditions are you looking for?  You're not likely to get much other than restatements of the definition of closed operator.

Comment: In particular, the closedness of the range doesn't really help much.  For example, suppose $X = U \oplus V$ with $\text{dom}(A) = (\text{dom}(A) \cap U) + (\text{dom}(A) \cap V)$.  The image of $U \cap \text{dom}(A)$ might be all of $Y$, in which case $\text{rng}(A)$ is certainly closed, but that says nothing about what happens on $V$.